# Trying to install install for MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install install for MySQL-python , but i have this error that require installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iwizu2ag\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iwizu2ag\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vnvrbcv_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\MySQL-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iwizu2ag\MySQL-python\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iwizu2ag\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iwizu2ag\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vnvrbcv_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\MySQL-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Actually , I have Microsoft visual c++ 15 installed on my device

Comment: i also installed today the latest from microsoft, but as far as i understand it you need the buid tools as well  i am trying https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe and will tell if it is enough

Comment: what are the build tools needed to install ?

Comment: as i said, when i am finshed ,. i will give yu an answer, the c++ drivers aren't enough it try to compile something and it needs for that special programs.an installed vs code 1.44 isn't also enough

Comment: Ok , I am waiting for you

Answer (score 0):

So after getting the same error message.

I did what the message said.

Downloaded and installed the build tools.

I couldn't find them on Micorsoft download page so here is a link

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe

After installing is selected the options in the image and it worked

[image]

Comment: i run it successfully