# How to Install mysqlclient for Django in windows 10?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

i am new in Django.i want to use Mysql database for my project.i am installing mysqlclient for that, but its showing below error.
i am using
--pip install mysql-python command for installing mysqlclient

```
Collecting mysql-python   Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB) Using legacy setup.py install for mysql-python, since package 'wheel' is not installed. Installing collected packages: mysql-python
    Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'f:\xampp\htdocs\django\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti26jpbi\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti26jpbi\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h90u4076\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'f:\xampp\htdocs\django\include\site\python3.8\mysql-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ti26jpbi\mysql-python\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\xampp\htdocs\django\scripts\python.exe' -u
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti26jpbi\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti26jpbi\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h90u4076\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'f:\xampp\htdocs\django\include\site\python3.8\mysql-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

i an using windows 10.
i appreciate if anyone can help me with this error.

Comment: use my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293962/5193536

Comment: `MySQL-python` only supports Python 2. Use `pip install mysqlclient` to install mysqlclient. Make sure you have 64-bit Python installed - that way it will install the wheel.

Comment: i am getting same error  with pip install mysqlclient .

Comment: It might be a similar error for `mysqlclient` but it won't be the same, so please show that error instead. As I said before the easiest solution is to switch to 64-bit Python then you won't have to build `mysqlclient`.

Answer (score 1):

I will point out 2 solutions. Choose based on your needs.

1. Easy solution. Please note that this is an alternative, not a fix. Also this will not get you the latest version. As long as it suits your needs might be good enough.

- Download the .whl that compatible with your Windows 10 version (x32/x64) from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)
- Install it: pip install <path_to_whl>
- Done!

2. Better solution. This is a fix for `pip install mysqlclient`. Please follow step by step although it's dummy, but it works:

- Go to: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/
- Download and install the x64 version;
- Move `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`;
- Go to: https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/c-connector
- Download and install latest C connector available for MS Windows (x64 bit)
- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include`
- Create a directory(folder) named: `mariadb`
- Copy contents from `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb`
- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib`
- Create a directory(folder) named: `mariadb`
- Copy contents from `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\lib` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\mariadb`
- Run `pip install mysqlclient`
- Done!

Test: Tested both above solutions using latest available configurations:

- python 3.10
- mysql 8.0.27
- django 3.2.9

FYI: Those are not the only 2 solutions. For instance if you dockerize, use a VM or simply use the new capability of windows 10 to have ubuntu as an app you can fix this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 tools containing the C++ compiler: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

OR

You can download pre-compiled binaries for many libraries here: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) (usual warnings about package sourcing applies)

Comment: Currently, there are [official wheels](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files) for the latest mysqlclient release for 64-bit Python on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download the mysqlclient from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient). just check the verion of your python and download the .whl file.

Then just copy the file name in command prompt go to the downloads folder and type

```
pip install {fullfile name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look carefully at this line in the error message you provided:

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

There is an answer to what are you looking for.